# Sending messages to client over Web socket. Each message has different time interval

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sockets, signalr

I'm developing an server/client app. The server pushes out a message to clients at timed intervals. Each message can have a different time attribute.

What's the best way to approach this? I could pause the thread but that seems a bit hacky. Is there a best practice for this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to use `SignalR` (you added a tag), a simple timer could do the job:

```
public sealed class MatchingSupervisor
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MatchingSupervisor));
    private readonly IHubContext _hub;
    private readonly Timer _timer;

    #region Singleton

    public static MatchingSupervisor Instance => SupervisorInstance.Value;

    // Lazy initialization to ensure SupervisorInstance creation is threadsafe
    private static readonly Lazy<MatchingSupervisor> SupervisorInstance = new Lazy<MatchingSupervisor>(() => 
            new MatchingSupervisor(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<YourHubClass>()));

    private MatchingSupervisor(IHubContext hubContext)
    {
        _hub = hubContext;
        _timer = new Timer(Run, null, 0, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    #endregion

    private async void Run(object state)
    {
        // TODO send messages to clients

        // you can use _timer.Change(newInterval, newInterval) here 
        // if you need to change the next interval
        var newInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
         _timer.Change(newInterval, newInterval);
    }
}
```

To ensure your timer restarts when the system or the app restarts (system went down, app recycle, etc), you should get an instance on the Owin Startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    private MatchingSupervisor _conversationManager;

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // TODO app configuration

        // Ensure supervisor starts
        _supervisor = MatchingSupervisor.Instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good approach. In my case I have a scenario such as message1: send and then wait for 30 secs, message2 send and then wait for 60 secs, etc. Should I supply this time parameter in the fourth argument of the Timer initializer?

Comment: Well, that depends on the logic of your app. Are you going to send those messages to all connected users at the same time? In that case you can change the timer interval every time you send a message or you can just use the timer to run it once and create a new one. If you need to send messages to specific users at different intervals, that would be a different question not related to push stuff from server to client

Comment: Edited the answer to change the interval

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Quartz.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/).

By your tags, I suppose you are using C#, so you can see the [Microsoft doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) about Task Class (this implements Threads)

Comment: You can also look for this tutorial: [Simulate a Windows Service using ASP.NET to wun scheduled jobs] (https://www.codeproject.com/kb/aspnet/aspnetservice.aspx)